# More evidence that we are going downhill

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are we Going down hill?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/are-we-going-down-hill)

[In my last post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/are-we-going-down-hill) a few people pointed out the that decline in average score and question count was not a good metric for showing the decline of this site.. So here is some additional evidence.

I Basically classified every question as  **Good**, **Bad** or **Ok**
**Good**= A score >1 and Open

**Ok**= A score =1 and Open

**Bad**= A score <0 or Closed

**Here is The Graph (Including a Line for total)**
[image]

Here is the SQL:

```
Select
    week.week
    ,good.cnt as Good
    ,ok.cnt as ok
    ,bad.cnt as bad
from 
    (select distinct 
        CAST(year(p.CreationDate) as char(4))+'-'+CAST(DATEPART(wk,p.CreationDate) as char(2)) as week 
        from Posts p
        where p.CreationDate>dateadd(yy,-1,getdate())) week
join 
    (select  
        CAST(year(p.CreationDate) as char(4))+'-'+CAST(DATEPART(wk,p.CreationDate) as char(2)) as week 
         ,count(1) as Cnt
        from Posts p
        where score>1 and Closeddate is Null
        group by   year(p.CreationDate),DATEPART(wk,p.CreationDate) 
    ) good on good.week=week.week
join 
    (select  
        CAST(year(p.CreationDate) as char(4))+'-'+CAST(DATEPART(wk,p.CreationDate) as char(2)) as week 
         ,count(1) as Cnt
        from Posts p
        where score=0 and Closeddate is Null
        group by   year(p.CreationDate),DATEPART(wk,p.CreationDate) 
    ) ok on ok.week=week.week
join 
    (select  
        CAST(year(p.CreationDate) as char(4))+'-'+CAST(DATEPART(wk,p.CreationDate) as char(2)) as week 
         ,count(1) as Cnt
        from Posts p
        where score<0 or Closeddate is not Null
        group by   year(p.CreationDate),DATEPART(wk,p.CreationDate) 
    ) bad on bad.week=week.week
order by week.week
```

Comment: Clearly the site is dead. Wait, does that make this a ghost account?

Comment: @Michael, I post these things because I want help make this place better. And the first step in doing that is smacking people out of denial.

Comment: @Morons The graph actually proves we are getting better, moving away from the troublesome early days when every crappy post was ridiculously upvoted... Help us clean up those early posts and the numbers will be quite different.

Comment: @Yannis is it also good that out total question count is Down 30% from One year ago? Please tell me, what metric will be good enough evidence for you?

Comment: @Morons In general, quality > quantity.

Comment: @Anna, What metric (If not Question Score) can i use to measure quality?

Comment: I don't mind a drop of even that much *or more* if the "questions" lost are the ones we are constantly closing. What are we losing? **Nothing.**

Comment: @Morons There are quite a few reasons why we would be getting less questions: 1) New SE sites, that are better homes for quite a few questions we used to accommodate, 2) Less crap finds it's way here from Stack Overflow, 3) We are doing a far better job cleaning up our own crap... Why are more questions automatically a good thing?

Comment: Ok, I understand.. For you, there is no evidence (or metric) that will is valid.

Comment: >>Why are more questions automatically a good thing : Simply because  participation is the life blood of any social site.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: @Michael both Quality AND Quantity are going down. These two should not be at odds with each other. The goal should be to increase both.

Comment: @Morons Thankfully Programmers is a Q&A site, not a social site...

Comment: @Yannis But it is and was always meant to be. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/12/building-social-software-for-the-anti-social.html

Comment: @Morons Great blog post, I love items 9 and 10 on the list... ;P

Comment: @All I'm not looking to argue with anyone, I simply think there is allot of room for improvement here.. And we should consider what those improvements should be. There is an absolutely culture of complacency here.. Any kind of negative talk if highly discouraged. I personally think it one of  the biggest problems we have.

Comment: @Yannis Jeff is a smart guy.. to bad he quit.

Comment: **"..Each community has a laser sharp focus with significant depth, and narrow breadth. This primarily benefits experts - the people who are able to answer those questions..."** ([from SO meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68229/165773))

Comment: Morons and @Rachel: Please continue to fight the good fight.

Answer (score 12):

I think the top answers on your previous post already explain the trends in this graph.  More people (myself included) are beginning to understand the direction that the Programmers community wants the site to go in, and we're voting and flagging accordingly.  The actual proportion of Good/Bad questions *asked* may have stayed the same (or even gotten a little better), but your data only shows how we're *reacting* to it with downvoting and close votes.  I've been spending a little bit of time each day voting on **new** questions that are good or bad.  I don't go back and vote on old ones nearly as much.