# Changing the FAQ to reflect the site's name

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

A while back I made a suggestion to [either rename the site to match the FAQ, or change the FAQ so it matches the site name](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2948/1130) to help clear up a lot of the confusion I see over what P.SE is for. That question was asked to see if this idea had any support, and I believe it does judging by the 25 upvotes it currently has, and the [other](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/600/misleading-site-title) [questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465/can-we-change-the-name-of-the-site) which were pointed out that ask the same thing.

The site name is the first, and often only, piece of information a user has to judge our site on. Since we can't change the site's name, this question is to ask **what kind of changes can we make to the FAQ to make it accurately reflect the site name, without going back to the mindless fun this site began as?**

I see a lot of confusion over the scope of P.SE, and I think [this recent MSO comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124923/where-in-the-stack-exchange-world-can-i-initiate-a-programming-related-discuss/124927#comment336347_124925) sums up what I've seen:

> no one recommends Programmers anymore because it's unclear what the
>   site's scope is and some of its users disagree strongly with what
>   others of its users think the site's scope entails

My suggestions are below. I wanted to post them all together in one answer since they I feel the suggestions make the most sense if you read them in order, but ultimately decided to separate them so we can comment, evaluate, and vote on each suggestion individually.

I feel this would go a long ways towards making the site scope match the site name, and clear up the confusion caused by the current differences. In addition, I am hoping this will help reconcile users from both sides of the site scope argument.

Please review and vote on the suggestions, or add your own.

Comment: Rachel we won't be changing the scope of the site by rewording the FAQ, that's unacceptable, scope definition must go through the normal Meta process. Please narrow this down to either be about clarifying the FAQ with respect to the current scope or be about changing the scope. Furthermore _no one_ agreed that the site's name is actually an issue.

Comment: @YannisRizos I thought 25 +votes on 1 question and at least 2 other questions on a small meta about the issue would show that there is a problem. Please tell me what "normal meta process" is, because I never saw it when the site scope changed to what it is now.

Comment: Yannis is right. I do think cleaning up the FAQ is probably a good idea, no scope changes should be introduced. Kind of like refactoring. You don't introduce functional changes when you refactor.

Comment: There are 25 +votes and 9 -votes on your question, which blends various issues together, and quite a few upvotes on answers that disagree with the premise of the question. Asking a simple Meta question "Is the name of the site misleading" would be a normal meta process. Your meta question as it is it's pretty pointless. As for whether the process is followed or not, read all 976 current Meta questions and then we can talk about it.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm not sure how much scope change would actually get done as a result of these changes. For example, questions like [How to mentor a Junior Developer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138396/how-to-mentor-a-junior-developer/138406#138406) is actually off-topic for our current scope, however is a great question for programmers so was left open. Questions such as these could no longer be pointed out as "but this one is left open even though the FAQ says it shouldn't be"

Comment: @YannisRizos There actually is [an old question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/600/misleading-site-title) that asks about the misleading site title, with 9 upvotes and 1 downvote. There are also other questions, including mine, which ask the same thing. I assumed posting it again would be a duplicate.

Comment: @YannisRizos And I don't think it's pointless because it's proposing an alternative way of doing things. I might not have the "SE Q&A format" right (mostly because I don't know what it is), but at least I can draw attention to the problem and possible solutions. You're the one who keeps telling me to present solutions, not just point out problems.

Comment: @Rachel It's pointless because you are mixing issues and there isn't an easy way to build consensus. Bringing attention to something you perceive as a problem is fine (and I upvoted your Meta question), but doing only that doesn't help towards defining the scope of the site.

Comment: @Rachel Re the [other question on changing the name](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/600/misleading-site-title): First notice that the top voted answer says "don't change the name, it won't help". Then, since it's an old question, if you feel that the issue hasn't been resolved do post a new Meta question, however make sure to include at least some strong indicators (if not solid evidence) that the issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming the site to match its FAQ or changing the FAQ to match the site name?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/renaming-the-site-to-match-its-faq-or-changing-the-faq-to-match-the-site-name)

Comment: @MarkTrapp This question is a follow-up of that one. I was told I need to offer specific solutions to problems we encounter, not just point out problems, so this meta question is an attempt to offer a specific solution to that problem. I thought a new meta post would be best since the other one is so old.

Comment: @Rachel Your question as-is is a rehash of a rehash of a rehash: there is no consensus that the site's FAQ does not accurately reflect the site's scope, and you have yet to provide a convincing argument the site's FAQ is fundamentally broken. The only one that seems to have any merit is mentioning the difference between P.SE & SO, but its justification is dubious (that it alone will make the FAQ—which ostensibly doesn't reflect the site's scope now—reflect the site's scope). This would fare much better if the specific changes you want to propose were done with separate, more cogent arguments.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Hrrrm alright. Originally all these were one long answer, and I only broke it up so we could talk about the suggestions individually. Would you like me to create a separate meta post about adding the difference between SO and SE, and about changing the FAQ to define on-topic by answer needed instead of by question topic?

Comment: @Rachel I think there's a much greater chance of getting a [meta-tag:status-completed] if you do it that way. I might have some more arguments you can use for P.SE & SO change: I'll ping you in chat.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Alright, thanks. I really wanted to get opinions/ideas on these suggestions and see if people are in favor of changes like this first (hence the `discussion` tag). I'd like to take the ideas which seem to have some support and make an actual proposal out of them which can be implemented, although I really don't care about the `[status-completed]` tag :)

Comment: This whole debate is waste of time.. No one reads the FAQ when first visiting the site, and no one ever will.

Comment: @Morons People do read the FAQ (usually existing SE users), however I've seen comments [like this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124923/where-in-the-stack-exchange-world-can-i-initiate-a-programming-related-discuss/124927#comment336347_124925) from SE users about our FAQ being confusing. In addition, the FAQ is what defines the site scope, so changes in the FAQ are reflected in the voting patterns of users of the site.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: [Existing proposal](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1838/1130) for this already exists, so I'm not making a new one. Go vote there to show your support if you'd like to implement this.

---

**1.5) Add the difference between Programmers.SE and SO**

The opening sentence should immediately be followed by this, which is one of the most frequently asked questions I have seen from users who participate in the stack exchange network:

> **[What's the difference between Programmers and StackOverflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/173/1130)**
>
> If you are standing at a whiteboard or discussing 
>   design concepts with your team, come to Programmers.
>   If you are sitting at a keyboard and writing code, you should go
>   to StackOverflow.

If users do not read any further, they should at least have a general idea of who and what the site is for.

Comment: This *might* be useful.

Comment: It's still too broad to be of any use to the typically panicking user who leaves the bad & broad (b&b) question.

Comment: @WorldEngineer I actually got the suggestion from [a user on SO's Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124923/where-in-the-stack-exchange-world-can-i-initiate-a-programming-related-discuss/124927#comment336732_124925) who thought that line should be in our FAQ because it states a short, simple, clear expectation about what the site is for. I believe it is the best one-line answer which defines our site scope.

Comment: I may not completely agree with the example provided but I **love** the idea about blatantly and unapologetically proclaiming the fundamental differences between the two sites on the FAQ.

Comment: @WorldEngineer The line is meant for users who only want to glance at the FAQ to see what this SE site is for, not for those who want to see if their question is on/off topic or not.

Comment: @maple_shaft I'm open to different wording for any of the suggestions. The existing stuff was only to provide an example and/or starting point :)

Comment: @Rachel I don't understand what the value is in accommodating users "who only want to glance at the FAQ"?

Comment: @YannisRizos I think almost every user that is familiar with the SE network will only want to glance at the FAQ to see what a site is about, not read the entire thing. These users know how the SE sites work, and only want to know what the site is about before deciding to spend time on it. In addition, I'm sure a large number of users who look at our FAQ just want to know if they should be posting a question on P.SE instead of SO.

Comment: From a UX perspective, no matter if the change is to this succinct version or the current wording, I would suggest putting the clause about Programmers *first*. After all, they are *here* when they are reading it (and it matches the order in the question). Better to focus immediately on what P.SE is rather than isn't, and secondarily on what SO is (i.e. not P.SE).

Comment: `I think almost every user that is familiar with the SE network will only want to glance at the FAQ to see what a site is about` Again, what is the value in doing anything to accommodate users who only want to glance at the FAQ. What value does that bring to the site? Why is it important for the site to attract users that won't bother reading the FAQ?

Comment: @YannisRizos Once again, this is a site run by a community of volunteers. If you are unwilling to support new users, you are essentially not supporting the very people who will support your site in the future.

Comment: @jcmeloni Good call, thanks :) I've edited the proposal to rearrange those sentences, but I will keep that in mind if we go with some other wording as well.

Comment: Rachel I'm fully committed in supporting new users that respect the community enough to at least read the FAQ and not just glance at it. Now please answer my question: Why should we accommodate users who fail to read the FAQ? What evidence do you have that failing to do so will somehow hurt the site? Other than a few off hand comments on MSO that is...

Comment: @YannisRizos I sincerely doubt you fully read the FAQ of every site you visit. Why should we expect our users to do what most users do not have to do? Websites should not require users to read the FAQ to use them correctly.

Comment: I thoroughly read the FAQ of every site that I'm interested in contributing to. We do not expect people to read the FAQ to use the website, but to ask questions and participate in general. The FAQ doesn't describe how to use a website but how to participate in a community. Fully reading the FAQ _before_ participating in the community is required, and that's just common sense. And because you have a tendency to read what you want and not what I write: The requirement is to _read_ the FAQ, if you did and didn't understand parts of it, we are always around to help.

Comment: @YannisRizos In that case, I'll just agree to disagree with you. FAQ stands for "Frequently Asked Questions", and "whats the difference between P.SE and SO" is one of the most frequently asked questions about our site. The FAQ should be used when you have a question, and think the question has been asked enough to have a answer posted somewhere. It should not be a manual on how to use a site.

Comment: Again: Our FAQ is **not** a manual on how to use a site, but a set of guidelines on how to ask questions and participate in the community. Differentiating ourselves from SO _may be_ important, accommodating users who don't read the FAQ is not (simply because they will fail to read _everything_ we put in there regardless).

Answer (score 1):

**1) Change opening line**

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers
>   who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions
>   about software development.

To start with, the existing opening line in the FAQ immediately limits questions to software-development questions only. If this were a site about software development only, I would expect it to be called `softwaredevelopment.se`, not `programmers.se`, and to be honest, I do not fully see why I should ask many of our questions on `softwaredevelopment.se` instead of stackoverflow.

I feel the starting line should be something less limiting, such as this:

> Programmers.StackExchange is a site for professional programmers who
>   are interested in collaborating and learning from each other to
>   improve their understanding of the software development process.

Answer (score 1):

**4) Remove the "What about subjective questions?" section**

We are no longer as tolerant as we once were on subjective questions, and I think the guidelines listed lead to problem questions, particularly the bit telling users that questions should "invite sharing experiences over opinions" (I think every one of these I've seen has been closed as a poll).

I feel we can do better by merging key parts of this section in with the "what kind of questions can I ask here" section.

The only thing I think we should keep from this section is the line that says

> Please [look around](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to [ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

(I have no idea why this is in the "subjective questions" section anyways)

Comment: `I think every one of these I've seen has been closed as a poll` Links?

Comment: Certain types of on topic questions like design questions are not a hard science and as such opinions are going to occur.  I don't think opinions are an awful answer if they can provide appropriate references and argue the opinion with facts and research.  Question: Are anemic data models bad? Answer1: No.  Transaction based web services demand them.  **(BAD ANSWER)** Answer2: Yes I think they are, according to [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) they are inherently at odds with OOP.  **(GOOD ANSWER)**

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Proposal seems to have support, so I've made a [separate meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3318/1130) to propose this change. The actual proposal put forth has been adjusted a bit based on user feedback.

---

**2) Change the style of how we define site scope**

This section currently has a list of what is on-topic, and what is not.

> If you have a question about…
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - design patterns
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - software licensing
>
> and it is not about…
>
> - career advice, including general workplace issues
> - personal lifestyle, including relationships, office politics, and non-programming activities
> - what language you should learn next,including which
>     technology is better
> - salary or compensation
> - résumé help
> - what project you should do next
> - programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead)
>
> …then you're in the right place to ask your question!

I feel this is a bad way of doing this because "Programmers" is an extremely broad topic that covers a type of person, not a specific item or activity. It seems unrealistic to have a comprehensive list of what types of questions are on-topic and what is not, especially since I think our site is best defined by the type of answer needed, not by the question topics.

So instead of trying to make a list of absolutely everything about programmers and if its on/off topic, I feel we should instead define what makes a question good for this site, which happens to be the type of answer they require.

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Questions asked should:
>
> - **Require an answer from a programmer specifically. They should not be ones that are better answered by another profession, or by
>     yourself**
>
>   A good example would be career-related questions. We are not career
>     guidance counselors, nor are we an HR department, so most career and
>     workplace questions will be closed as off-topic unless the question
>     can be best answered by a programmer, such as asking [if it's detrimental
>     to your programming career to stay in one job too long](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/74626/1130).
> - **They should ask for a single answer, not a list of answers**
>
>   For example, asking any form of [What kind of [X] is best for a
>     programmer?](http://a.b) is off-topic and will likely be closed. The end result
>     is almost always a huge list of everyone's favorite [X], and that list
>     will get outdated as time and technology progresses.
>
>   Instead, consider how you can [rephrase your question so it is seeking
>     a single answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) that can only be answered by a programmer. For
>     example, asking [What are some good books about development
>     methodologies?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12833/1130) would be closed, however asking for a *specific*
>     book with a limited scope, such as [Is there a canonical book on the Agile software
>     development methodology?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7859/1130) is OK.
> - **Should be relevant to a programmer's to professional growth, not their personal amusement**
>
>   The question should relate to a
>     programmer's professional life, not their personal life. Questions on
>     programmer lifestyle are off-topic unless they relate to their
>     professional life, such as asking [I don't program in my spare
>     time. Does that make me a bad developer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/48698/1130).
>
>   We want a site that we can continuously learn and grow from, not one that
>     simply amuses us when we're bored at work.
> - **Has a clear answer can be agreed upon by the majority of programmers**
>
>   [We are a Q&A site, not a discussion board](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/1130).
>
>   Don't ask questions about [What 
>     language/technology should I learn next?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/112504/1130) or [Is A better than B?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)
>     because we are not interested in questions that lead to chatty, open-ended 
>     discussions
>
>   Instead, visit our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers) for open-ended discussions with other programmers
> - **Should be written in such a way that the question is useful by more than just you**
>
>   In other words, don't give us your life story with your question.
>     Simply tell us the relevant facts, and state your question.
>
>   We work hard to build and maintain a library of questions which can
>     be referenced by any programmer, not just you. Help us maintain our site.

Hopefully this will stop the number of "but so and so is on/off topic in the FAQ" comments I see, because the scope of this site is really defined by the answers, not the questions.

**Edit**

There are some concerns below about this becoming a big wall of text, and I agree. Perhaps we could use [more](http://a.b)/[less](http://a.b) links like we have in the current FAQ to hide examples unless the user is looking for examples. If we are unable to collapse the text or make this easy to read, we could also just display bullet points that link to meta questions on relevant topics.

Comment: You can't see the history but we went through phase where the FAQ was a big wall of text like this and it just didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisF Use the "more/less" options, or shorten it. The idea is to give a few bullet points (in this case, 5), and some examples to help clarify. I remember the wall of text it used to be, and the problem was that it was a wall of text, not some clearly defined, easy to read bullet points.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisF that it's a bit verbose and people aren't going to read all of that, but overall, I do think it captures guidance about what's on-topic better than a list of "ask these, but not these". Although I don't like the term "programmer" and would favor "software developer" or "software development professional" - professionally, I am not a programmer. In fact, less than 50% of my time is spent writing code. Most of my time at work is typically doing the work of a software architect or on software engineering process improvement.

Comment: I think a far better way to approach this would be to write clear Meta questions for each topic (either on or off) and link to them from the FAQ. We can have answers with example questions, etc...

Comment: @ThomasOwens I agree that `software developer` is a better description, but the site is called `programmers`, which is why I used that word. To many of us, `programmer` is synonymous with `software developer`. I'm really hoping we can implement some kind of "how to ask questions" instead of "ask this, not this" style of FAQ

Comment: Although it's often synonymous, I feel it's off-putting to many people who don't program. I think it's important to attract architects and designers, process improvement specialists, software project managers, and so on. I think what we're going through is very much like [what Database Administrators is going through](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/495/database-administrators-needs-to-die).

Comment: @ThomasOwens I would be very happy to change the site name to `softwaredevelopers.se`. I would either like a site name change, or some tweaks to the scope. I am unable to do anything about the site name change, however I can possibly influence the FAQ which is why I made this question.

Comment: The current topics list in the faq is *not comprehensive*, but merely illustrative.  It was never the intention to make it a comprehensive list of what is on-topic and what isn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand that, however my proposal is to change the way we define an on-topic question to show that a question is defined as on-topic by the answer it requires, not the subject of the question.

Comment: This may be what Yannis meant (I don't think so), but what if we had something like Rachel's bullet points but dropped the support text from the faq, and made those points links to related meta questions.  This would greatly reduce the wall of text effect, but still include points which I think are very important to posting acceptable questions but are currently very tough to dig up out of the meta posts on programmers, on stack overflow, and from blog posts.  I would skip the last bullet point if we keep the big Venn Diagram.  We could keep the current on-topic list if we do this.

Comment: The "wall of text" problem is partially solved by having detailed FAQ questions on the meta sites. For example, link only questions are [already covered in the site faq in brief](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion), but are also covered in much better detail [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way).

Comment: @psr My personal preference would be more/less links such as the current FAQ has to expand/collapse details, although including links to meta if there are specific examples is a good idea. I've updated the suggestion to include this.

Comment: We can't use "more/less" links, they only appear on the network wide sections, we can only edit the top part and can't brake it into sections.

Answer (score -2):

**3) Remove the blue and white "Question Applies To:" graphic**

As much as I like our fancy blue circle showing a question should apply to "All Programmers", I think we should get rid of it.

It is very large, quite eye-catching, and promotes too many career-related questions since one of the circles is "All Careers". I feel if we are going to have a graphic this large and colorful in our FAQ, it'd better be one that clearly and completely defines the site scope.

Perhaps if we made it much smaller we could fit it next to the careers-is-off-topic section, but in its current state I don't think it should be in our FAQ.

[image: Fancy blue circle]

Comment: Well, if our diagram is good enough for [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/268/update-faq-to-better-define-what-kind-of-questions), it's good enough for me.

Comment: @YannisRizos Their FAQ does not contain that graphic, and the top voted answer is undecided about if such a graphic would help at all. And anyways, just because someone else does something doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: Similarly just stating that it's wrong doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: @YannisRizos You build websites, right? Would you build a website, which had a single, large, eye-catching graphic which takes up most of a screen but does not fully explain the website? No, that's bad website design.

Comment: Although I'm primarily a back end web developer, my work rarely involves UI & UX, and when it does I take my cues from specialists. Also, I fail to see what my job (or yours) have anything to do with the discussion. I thought we were discussing the merits of the proposal, not what we do for a living.

Comment: @YannisRizos That's the merit for my proposal. A graphic that large and eye catching should not be in our FAQ unless it fully explains the site scope, which it doesn't. It might not be so bad if we had other graphics which illustrate other points, but it is our only graphic on the faq and only illustrates one point. Either make it smaller so it fits by the "career-questions-are-off-topic" section, or remove it.

Comment: Yay! More graphics! I can support that, especially if we put some cute kittens in there...

Answer (score -8):

**5) Remove the "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" section**

We've already listed what kind of questions can be asked here. We should not need to list the kind of questions that cannot be asked here. It only adds to the wall-of-text that is our FAQ.

**Edit**

Suggestion dropped due to strong disagreement